# How is interferometry used to measure distances?

Tags: interferometry, radio, radiometry

I understand how a basic interferometer works, and how Michaelson used an interferometer to more-or-less disprove the “luminiferous anther”, but, analytically, how would one go about using an interferometer to measure distances?

Answer (score 0):

The thing about interferometers such as those used in gravitational wave detectors is that they don't actually measure distance; rather, they indirectly measure the *relative* changes in distances by tracking the effect of those changes on the phases of the interfered fields.

In the case of the LIGO detectors, which are Michelson interferometers, there are two orthogonal "arms" of length $L$ with light round-trip travel time $t_{rt} = 2L/c$, usually called the North arm and the East arm. Analytically, one can assume that the length of one arm --take the North arm -- is perfectly stable and the other arm therefore contains all relative length changes. These length changes, $\Delta l(t)$, couple into the phase of the light $\phi$ via the wavenumber $k = \frac{1}{\lambda}$ with $\Delta \phi(t) = k\Delta l(t)$.

When the light in the two arms are combined on the central beamsplitter, their fields are superimposed:

$A = A_{East, 0}e^{i(\omega t_{rt} - kL_{East})} + A_{North, 0}e^{i(\omega t_{rt} - kL_{North} + \Delta \phi(t))} + c.c. $

The stable accumulated phases of light traveling in the interferometer can be gathered up:

$A = A_{East, 0}e^{i\phi_{East}} + A_{North, 0}e^{i(\phi_{North} + \Delta \phi(t))} + c.c.$

Now the *intensity* of the field in the output of the interferometer is $I = |A|^2$:

$I = |A_{East, 0}|^2 + |A_{North, 0}|^2 + A_{East,0}A_{North,0}e^{i(\phi_{East} - \phi_{North} - \Delta\phi)} + A_{North,0}A_{East,0}e^{i(\phi_{North} - \phi_{East} + \Delta\phi(t))}$.

Now with some sum-and-difference formula application you can isolate the value of $\phi(t)$ -- and therefore the changes in distance in the interferometer -- based on the power measured $P(t)$, which is just this intensity integrated over the surface of a photodiode at the output.

Answer (score 0):

Interferometer is based on the principle of Interference of Waves. Interference happens because of **phase/path difference**. So if you can find a way to link the quantity you wish to measure with phase/path difference, you are good to go.

We don't usually measure distances using Interferometers, because there is no simple way to relate distance to path "difference". Rather we can measure difference in distance/ relative changes in distance to "Path difference".

Comment: This is true, but it is possible to measure absolute distance using interferometry.  Using a low-coherence source in an Michaelson interferometer, the distance from the beamsplitter to the object in question when fringes are observed is equal to the distance between the beamsplitter and the reference mirror.

Comment: Why do you want to use interferometers to measure distance as in what in your opinion is the advantage of such a measurement? You know, we could directly use speed of light to measure distance. Interferometry works under the principle of what the phase difference between waves are. Now the phase itself keep resetting back after every wavelength distance or so, meaning there is no one to one map between distance and absolute phase (adding $n \lambda$ would give you same phase).